# still showing Deleted files when using MediaStore to get files from Folder

Tags: android

I Downloaded files using `DownloadManager` & then I uninstalled app, files also deleted as per new behaviour of `DownloadManager`.
But When I fetching files of perticular folder files, then I am still showing that files in list.

Comment: You have to wait a while until the "android media scanner" discovers that the image-files do not exist any more. the scanner will then remove the meda db entries and the cached thumbnails of the deleted files.

Comment: But I am doing operations with Audio Files, not an image file

Comment: the media-database and the media scanner works with images, audio and video. with android 5.0 and newer there is a api to tell the media scanner to rescan certain files/dirs and i assume that there are also apps that can trigger the rescan.

Comment: I am waited already 3-4 hours but not scanned till now

Comment: if the files were on sd card unmount sdcard and then remount it. this will trigger a rescan.